# 2 way binding with an array

Tags: ember.js

I am passing an array of strings from a controller to a component. There is logic in my component that will add/remove strings on the array using pushObject/removeObjects. This works fine however the controller is not notified that array changed. The only way I am able notify my controller is call action passing it the changed array. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After the content of an array changed with `pushObject/removeObjects`, observers and computeds are notifed. Have a look at [computed properties and aggregate data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) section of guide. Sample [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/74587623ceca81a01c28b260ab0ef904?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

But this is not a better way for most cases! "Sending an action from the component and modifing the array in the controller" fits to the DDAU (data down, action up).